# Product of the Euler phi function

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, induction, prime-factorization, totient-function

Prove the following statement: If $n, m\in\mathbb{Z} $ and $g=$gcd$(n, m) $ then is 
$$\varphi(m, n) =\frac{ \varphi(m) \varphi(n) g} {\varphi(g)}. $$

**Hint:** Prove the statement with induction  above the number of common prime divisors.

How can I do the first step of induction?

Comment: start by proving that $\varphi(mn) = \varphi(m) \varphi(n)$ when $gcd(m,n) = 1$